# Footnote inline styling with kableExtra

Tags: r, kable

Why the following works for caption and doesn't for footnote? How do i do that in the footer?

```
library(kableExtra)

mtcars[1:5,] %>%
kable(caption = "why this <span style='color: red;'>is red</span>") %>%
  footnote(general_title = "",
           general = "and this<span style='color: red;'>isn't?</span>")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the `escape` parameter is set to `TRUE` in `footnote`. This means that any html that you try to include in your footnote will be html-escaped and therefore it will be rendered as a string rather than being interpreted as actual html.

Fortunately, you can just turn it off:

```r
library(kableExtra)

mtcars[1:5,] %>%
kable(caption = "why this <span style='color: red;'>is red</span>") %>%
  footnote(general_title = "",
           general = "and this<span style='color: red;'> is too?</span>", 
           escape = FALSE)
```

[image]